# Xcode Server continuous integration and cocoa pods issue Pods-resources.sh: Permission denied

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, cocoapods, xcode-server

I am using Xcode Server for build automation for project contains pods and committed on the source control repository but i got this error.

Bot Issue: error. Shell Script Invocation Error.
**Issue:**

```
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/c9ae12e7aee586b5d98bd25cdb00aa59/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/TTouchApp.build/Debug-ip.
Integration Number: 2.
Integration URL: https://OSXServer.local/xcode/bots/05AB454/integrations
Description: /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/c9ae12e7aee586b5d98bd25cdb00aa59/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/TTouchApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TTouchApp.build/Script-DF2BA7C1B92E426DBC1E97C5.sh: 

line 2: /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/c9ae12e7aee586b5d98bd25cdb00aa59/Source/TTouch/TTouchApp/Pods/Pods-resources.sh: Permission denied.
```

Comment: FYI, this error happen every time i check out the project from the source control and i solve it by running this command "chmod a+x "Path"" but how i solve it at the integration time ??

Answer (score 1):

This problem can happen because teamsserver does not own the files. You can run a pre-build action that sets the owner to teamsserver. something like `sudo chown teamsserver:teamsserver "path"`

Make sure teamsserver is in your sudoers file.

Comment: Did you mean this path /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/b03a74fb725283c3db91460f9f00f706/Source/TTouch/TTouchApp/Pods/Pods-resources.sh ??

Comment: Yes, the path to whichever file you are getting the permission denied error.

Comment: When creating new bot, i added before integration trigger with this script sudo chown teamsserver:teamsserver "/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/c9ae12e7aee586b5d98bd25cdb00aa59/Source/TTouch/TTouchApp/Pods/Pods-resources.sh" but the issue still happen !! please how to make sure that teamsserver is in my sudoers file. i couldn't find the teamsserver folder.

Comment: The root for teamsserver is in /Var/teamsserver but it is not actually created unless you create it. To add teamsserver to the sudoers file use `sudo visudo` EDIT for Mac syntax. Go here:http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/06/add-user-sudoers-file-mac/

Comment: Huh, try making the file 777 before you commit it?

Comment: Congo! Just run sudo chown -R <xcodeServerUser> <ProjectRootPath>, as a root user or add  <xcodeServerUser> in your sudoers file the run the above command without sudo.

Answer (score -1):

This might have to do with the Ruby's version with your version of OS X. Please check that version and update as CocoaPods uses Ruby.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to this shell script failure.

Comment: ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]